# What is the right way to install codesniffer to Aptana Studio standalone version?

Tags: php, drupal, aptana, aptana3, phpcodesniffer

I followed this guide for eclipse integration on drupal:
https://drupal.org/node/1420004

I tried to install PTI plugin to Aptana 
(Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.1.201306062137, with Eclipse Platform Version: 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q)
, but got a lot requirement missing errors.
Then I enable Eclipse Indigo Update Site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo) in my Aptana, and installed it successfully this time.

Then I config it like this:

[image]

But it just don't work!

I have installed php codesniffer and pear library, it works perfectly in command-line, and git pre-commit hook, but I can't get it work in Aptana.
Even I right click on a file, the PHP Codesniffer is grey and unclickable.

I wonder what is the right way to install codesniffer to Aptana Studio ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to set up the "PHP Executer". Use the link on the side of that select-box and configure one, poiting to the php binary you have. It probably is  `/usr/bin/php5`. If the .ini file is required, it'll probably reside in `/etc/php5/cli/` or `/etc/php5/apache2/`.

If those are not correct, you can execute  and retrieve the location of that information.

I needed to set this up in order to have my codesniffer working. I couldn't find how to make it work without clicking in the button in the editor's toolbar, but It worked.

[image: config 1]

[image: config 2]